# How to import SVG's in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm migrating my react website to nextjs. I have one assets folder at the root which contains lots of svgs and I have one constants.js file where I'm importing all the SVG's as ReactComponent. I would like to know how to convert this part of code in nextjs.

Error message:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../assets/skills/html5.svg'
> 1 | import { ReactComponent as HTML } from "../../../assets/skills/html5.svg";
  2 | import { ReactComponent as CSS } from "../../../assets/skills/css.svg";
```

constants.js

```
import { ReactComponent as HTML } from "../../../assets/skills/html5.svg";
import { ReactComponent as CSS } from "../../../assets/skills/css.svg";

export const SKILLS = [
  {
    name: "html",
    image: HTML, // SVG Component
  },
  {
    name: "css",
    image: CSS,
  },
]
```

Folder Structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can setup SVGR into your project and add them as regular react components. Your code could end up looking something like this

```js
export const SKILLS = [
  {
    name: "html",
    image: <Html className="html"/>, // SVG Component
  },
  {
    name: "css",
    image: <Css className="css"/>,
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how should i import SVGs in the constants.js file?

Comment: Just like a regular file you can assign it any name you like, e,g import Html from "./assets/html.svg"